# Increment value from expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, code-generation, linq-expressions

I want to write a closure and increment it's value but i'm not able to do it. Here is my code

```
        int i = 0;
        Expression<Func<bool>> closurExpression = () =>
                                                  {
                                                      i++;
                                                      return i != 0;
                                                  };
```

but i get multuple errors about `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree` or `An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator` etc. Is it possible without using external tools as Mono.Cecil etc?

---

for the question: why am I asking for it. I want to write a simple wrapper (for a signature `Func<T,T> at least` that will calculate count of calls. For example:

```
Wrapper<int> wrapper = () => 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   wrapper();
int calls = wrapper.Calls; // 10;
```

my first realisation was:

```
class FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TResult> function;
    public int Calls { get; set; }

    private FunctionWithCounter(Func<T, TResult> function)
    {
        Calls = 0;
        this.function = function;
    }
    public static implicit operator FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func)
    {
        return new FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>(func);
    }

    public TResult this[T arg]
    {
        get
        {
            Calls++;
            return function(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

but after i get that recurcive functions won't work properly. For example for this code

```
int fact(int n) { return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1); }
```

Calls count will be 1 for any n. So idea is: get source function, and inject increment of Calls for every call of method increment it. All inner calls of method `somefunc` should be replaced by our method `funcWithInjection`, in this case we'll catch recursive functions too. Here is my code, but it doesn't work (except inject, so this code really increments a field value, but I cannot add source's method body to the tail and compile it, you can play with it if you will):

```
public class FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult> where T : new()
{
    private readonly Func<T, TResult> _functionWithInjection;
    private int _calls;
    public int Calls
    {
        get
        {
            return _calls;
        }
    }

    public FunctionWithCounter(Func<T, TResult> function)
    {
        _calls = 0;
        var targetObject = function.Target ?? new object();
        var dynMethod = new DynamicMethod(new Guid().ToString(), typeof(TResult), new[] { targetObject.GetType(), typeof(T), typeof(FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>) }, true);

        var ilGenerator = GenerateInjection(dynMethod);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var resDelegate = dynMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>, TResult>), targetObject);
        var functionWithInjection = (Func<T, FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>, TResult>)resDelegate;
        var targetMethodBody = function.Method.GetMethodBody();
        Debug.Assert(targetMethodBody != null, "mbody != null");

        //here i need to write method body in the tail of dynamic method.

        _functionWithInjection = function;
        _functionWithInjection = t =>
        {
            functionWithInjection(t, this);
            return default(TResult);
        };
        //finally here should be _functionWithInjection = t => functionWithInjection(t, this);
    }

    private ILGenerator GenerateInjection(DynamicMethod method)
    {
        var callsFieldInfo = GetType().GetField("_calls", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Debug.Assert(callsFieldInfo != null, "callsFieldInfo != null");
        var ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, callsFieldInfo);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, callsFieldInfo);
        return ilGenerator;
    }

    public static implicit operator FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func)
    {
        return new FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>(func);
    }

    public TResult this[T arg]
    {
        get
        {
            return _functionWithInjection(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

My second realisation was based on Emit API, but it's too complex and It was unfinished for a long time...

So now this is my 3rd try and i want to use expressions. Шt should look something like this:

```
    public FunctionWithCounter(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> function)
    {
        Action action = () => _calls++;
        Expression<Action> closurExpression = () => action();
        var result = Expression.Block(closurExpression, function);
        _functionWithInjection = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,TResult>>(result).Compile();
    }
```

*sorry for my english, but i really want to realize this idea*

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I've given an answer, but it's really a case of getting round the exact rules of the compiler while still violating the spirit of those rules.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can do sidestep the rules using `Interlocked.Increment`:

```
int i = 0;
Expression<Func<bool>> expression = () => Interlocked.Increment(ref i) != 0;
```

... but I would be *very* cautious about doing so. I wouldn't expect many pieces of code which deal with expression trees to handle this terribly cleanly, given the side-effect involved.

The above does seem to *work*, in terms of behaving how I'd expect it to:

```
int i = -2;
Expression<Func<bool>> expression = () => Interlocked.Increment(ref i) != 0;
var del = expression.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(del()); // True
Console.WriteLine(del()); // False
Console.WriteLine(del()); // True
Console.WriteLine(del()); // True
Console.WriteLine(i);     // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your first approach was cleaner and ok for simple, non-recursive cases. 
If you allow your wrapped functions to be aware of recursion, you can take it a little further and make the wrapper an argument to the function itself:

```
 class RecursiveFunctionWithCounter<T, TResult> 
 {
    private readonly Func<T, RecursiveFunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>, TResult> function;
    public int Calls { get; set; }

    public RecursiveFunctionWithCounter(Func<T, RecursiveFunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>, TResult> function)
    {
        Calls = 0;
        this.function = function;
    }


    public TResult this[T arg]
    {
        get
        {
            Calls++;
            return function(arg, this);
        }
    }
 }
```

And use it like this:

```
var rw = new RecursiveFunctionWithCounter<int, int>(
        (n, self) => { return n < 2 ? 1 : n * self[n - 1]; }
);

int rr = rw[3]; // rr=6
int rc = rw.Calls; // rc=3
```

On the other hand, if what you really want to do is instrument some existing methods in your code, consider doing a little [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) for instance, this is an [example](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/performance) of an aspect that increments a performance counter on each method call). This way you could just add an attribute like `IncrementPerformanceCounterAttribute` to your methods and the AOT library will do the rest.

Comment: At least, it works (unlike my solution). If not think about perfomance, it's very good. What's about AOP: I don't want to use any attribute for external code, everything should be done innerly in this class. For user it shouldn't differ from a simple Delegate, except additional field Calls and `foo[x]` notion instead of `foo(x)`. Perhaps, Rosylin postprocessing could help me, but it itsn't done yet